# Where to add ip link settings so they will execute on boot?

Tags: raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi 0 W which I am setting up to share a USB device, I want to add the following somewhere so they are executed on boot:

```
    sudo ip link set dev can0 type can bitrate 500000
    sudo ip link set dev can0 up
```

I have already put into /etc/network/interfaces

```
############### CAN BUS CONFIG ###########################
auto can0
iface can0 inet manual
    pre-up ip link set $IFACE type can bitrate 500000 listen-only off
    up /sbin/ifconfig $IFACE up
    down /sbin/ifconfig $IFACE down
```

I'm not really sure what the above enables or its benefits, can anyone explain?

The OS on the Raspberry Pi 0 W is:

```
Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I modified /etc/rc.local and add the lines:

```
ip link set dev can0 type can bitrate 500000
ip link set dev can0 up
```

Everything works great now....or it did, I spoke to soon I also needed to add:

```
usbip --debug bind -b 1-1
usbip -d
```

For some reason which I don't understand, executing usbip -d kills the can0 which is then no longer visible when typing:
`ip link`